# Is it possible to make a JUnit5 Extension implement an interface that is fulfilled by the extended class?

Tags: java, junit5

I would like to write a [JUnit5 Extension](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-extensions) that extends my test class,

```
@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
public class MyTestClass {

  @Test myTest1() {}

  @Test myTest2() {}

  // ...
}
```

However, my test class also implements a certain interface, so it looks more like this:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
  SomeClient getSomeClient();
  SomeClient getSomeClientAsAdministrator();
}

@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
public class MyTestClass implements SomeInterface {

  @Test myTest1() {}

  @Test myTest2() {}

  // ...

  SomeClient getSomeClient() {
    // ...
  }

  SomeClient getSomeClientAsAdministrator() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

No mysteries so far.

But now, I want those interface implementations to be available to the extension as well, *e.g.*

```
public class MyExtension implements BeforeEachCallback, SomeInterface
{

  @Override
  public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
    // be able to use getSomeClient();
  }
}
```

How can I set up my classes to achieve this? (Or, what is the inherent flaw or code smell against doing this?)

Comment: I'm not sure I like this setup. That said, you can use [`ExtensionContext#getRequiredTestInstance()`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtensionContext.html#getRequiredTestInstance()), check if it is an instance of `SomeInterface`, and then cast to `SomeInterface` in order to call a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`@RegisterExtension`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-programmatic) annotation which allows you to construct your extension instance manually.

> When an extension is registered declaratively via @ExtendWith, it can
>   typically only be configured via annotations. In contrast, when an
>   extension is registered via @RegisterExtension, it can be configured
>   programmatically — for example, in order to pass arguments to the
>   extension’s constructor, a static factory method, or a builder API.

It sounds like `SomeClient` is provided from elsewhere (a DI like Spring perhaps) but you need it in `MyExtension`. Assuming this scenario, you can start with something like:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MyTestClass {
  @Autowired SomeClient someClient;
  @RegisterExtension
  MyExtension myExtension = new MyExtension(someClient);
}
```

Comment: I guess there's a `@RegisterExtension` missing in the source code. 
Other than that it looks like a reasonable alternative to the solution I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is to use `getTestInstance()` on the context object:

```
public class MyExtension implements BeforeEachCallback {
    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {

        context.getTestInstance().ifPresent(instance -> {
            if (instance instanceof SomeInterface) {
                SomeInterface some = (SomeInterface) instance;
                System.out.println(some.getSomeClient());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What you can see here is two things:

1. There might not be a test instance object, e.g. in a `BeforeAllCallback` because test instances are usually created per test.
2. A cast is required. That means you should check if your test instance really does implement `SomeInterface`

Having said that, I'm not really sure why you'd want to go down that rather complicated route. What's `MyExtension` supposed to abstract from?

Comment: The extension should not need to know anything about the test class. The use of SomeInterface is just a fig leaf over the problem. @RegisterExtension is designed specifically for this scenario

Comment: @drekbour Well, there are generic extensions which shouldn’t know anything about the domain you’re testing; those are most common and often from a 3rd party. Extensions I built within my project can have a dedicated scope and assume more about where they are being applied. With a more specific problem description a better approach to the underlying issue might come to mind.